# Why am I able to add an element even if I have fixed the capacity of an ArrayList?

Tags: c#

Code below:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

        // fixing capacity
        a.Capacity = 2;

        // adding elements
        a.Add(2);
        a.Add(3);
        a.Add(1);
        a.Add(4);

        foreach (int j in a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(j);

        }

        Console.WriteLine(a.Capacity);
        Console.WriteLine(a.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: The capacity grows automatically. It's not there as a restriction.

Comment: Your question is already answered by the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.arraylist.capacity). Read it: *"Capacity is always greater than or equal to Count. If Count exceeds Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is automatically increased by reallocating the internal array before copying the old elements and adding the new elements."*

Comment: Read the documentation for the operations you're performing.  They make it rather clear what you're doing

Comment: Why are you using ArrayList? That is a legacy class from .NET 1.1 and is not recommended for new development.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList's Capacity would increase automatically if more items are added to the List. *(Not really sure why you are using `ArrayList`, If you are using .Net framework 2.0 or higher then  consider using `List<T>` which is type safe)*
See [ArrayList.Capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.arraylist.capacity) property

> Capacity is always greater than or equal to Count. If **Count exceeds
>   Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is automatically
>   increased** by reallocating the internal array before copying the old
>   elements and adding the new elements.

Comment: I assume the reason for this is so that you can specify an expected capacity and have better control over when the framework will resize the internal collection

Comment: @Charleh, I am pretty sure that reason holds for `List<T>`, may be it is true for `ArrayList`, but not really sure about it.